# How to call SimpleJpaWriter methods from RepositoryItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-batch

I want to use `RepositoryItemWriter` to write batch entities using the default implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository`.

```
@Autowired
private MyCrudRepository crudDao;

RepositoryItemWriter<HrsGiataId> w = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
w.setRepository(crudDao);
w.setMethodName("deleteInBatch");

public interface MyCrudRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {}
```

But the code above will not work as the `w.setMethodName` requires a method name from the `CrudRepository` interface, even though the default implementation for the crudrepository is `SimpleJpaRepository`, which has the `deleteInBatch()` method.

So, what can I do to make use of the spring crud repository specific jpa method?

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the writer requires a method from the `CrudRepository`.  You should be able to specify any method name you want.  If not, I'd raise that as a bug in Jira (https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH/).

Comment: Indeed it need child of CrudRepository else throws exception